# How to use window.location.href.replace to switch language in the href url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link that is used to switch languages in my site. When the user click on the link I want it to direct user to the chinese version of the page that is located inside the /ch/ folder.

For example, when user is on mysite.com/account/en/index.html, when click on the link, user should be redirected to mysite.com/account/ch/index.html

I tried the below code but it is not working. Anyone know a better code?

```
<li class="lang"><a id="langswitch" href="javascript: window.location.href.replace('/en/', '/ch/');" ><img src="/images/account/buttons/chinese.jpg" alt="chinese language" align="top" /></a></li>
```

Comment: `ch` usually refers to Switzerland; use `zh` to refer to Chinese! see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag and http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/languageid.jsp?a=zh&l=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe all that you are missing is

`window.location = window.location.href.replace('/en/', '/ch/');`

Comment: this works for me, my final code is: <li class="lang"><a id="langswitch" href="#ch" onclick="window.location = window.location.href.replace('/en/', '/ch/')"><img src="/images/account/buttons/chinese.jpg" alt="chinese language" align="top" /></a></li>

Answer (score 1):

why cant you use

```
<li class="lang"><a id="langswitch" href="mysite.com/account/cn/index.html" ><img src="/images/account/buttons/chinese.jpg" alt="chinese language" align="top" /></a></li>
```

Comment: I think the reason they're not using a regular link is so that the anchor would work to switch to the current page on the Chinese site, instead of always going to index.html.

Comment: Then there is no point of using a anchor tag instead
<li class="lang" id="langswitch"><img src="/images/account/buttons/chinese.jpg" alt="chinese language" align="top" /></li>

add onclick event to #langswitch